# Send notification on mysql update , android

Tags: mysql, database, notifications, row

lets say it simply.

i have an application which get news from ONLINE mysql and im trying to send notification to the user (who installed app) anytime i inserted new record.

**IMPORTANT :** I cant use GCM becuze google does not support my country(IRAN) and i cant use it so.

I searched and saw and article which was saying we have to check mysql rows evey X time , and if there is a new record and there was new row alarm the user .. he even gave codes but i cant find the article!

so i  was hoping to help me without gcm and somthing like what i said.

Thanks

Comment: You already mentioned the approach for a solution. You do not need the article. You just implement a batch process running once a minute that checks the database for entries younger than the last time the check was performed.

Comment: well can u please give me the solution link? i exactly ment what u said... @arkascha

Comment: @arkascha well ? can i have that?

Comment: Sorry, no, I do not have a link to some article you might have read. There is no "the solution link" I am afraid... But the approach seems to be pretty clear. What part is it that you have questions to?

Comment: To be able for us to offer more specific help you would have to post much more information about your issue. For example: what technology do you use on the server side? Or do you want to _directly_ connect to a database server that is exposed in the internet? That would be highly insecure in my eyes! Typically one has some sort of processing layer in between, like php or java, with the layer taking care of all the authorization and validation aspects...

Comment: that part checking rows from database... u know i can design a php file that checks number of rows in a table and show in php file and even getting them in android app , but the thing i dont know is to how check it every 1 minute and app run at startup ( for this checking gets enable)... thanks , plz help me @arkascha

Comment: You did not answer to my question about what platform or technology you use on the server side. I can only _assume_ you might want to say that you are using php? Is that the case?

Comment: umm i actully i didnt get u , here is my server files . persiancoder.tk/rapnews , i hope u get it ... @arkascha

Comment: Sorry, no, I do not get it. Please do not post links to arbitrary sites here. Add your code (the relevant parts only) to your question, there is an `edit` button below it. Do _not_ post additional information here in comments.

Comment: look i think we are getting far! MY EXAMPLE :  there is a php file that show row table (int) if there is 2 row it will just show 2 in php file ... so i can get the number from app but i dont know how to check if the number has gotted more and how to explain to app to do this job(checking rows) every x minute @arkascha

Comment: You can use a `cron` job to execute a script every minute and you do _not_ query the whole table each time to find out the number of entries. You save a timestamp indicating when the script has check last and only retrieve those entries that are younger. All that does not solve your idea to "push" something to the client (which is impossible). You have to poll on a regular base from the client, either on a regular base (what email applications do) or by using a "long time poll", something like an ajax request which stay open until the server decides to send some news.

Comment: umm forget it! can u please give me a tip how to create a stratup on boot for my app (only the checking news part)? i dont want to run the whole app . i hope u get what i mean... :) @arkascha

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that last comment. But I will "forget it", as you suggested. OK.

Comment: how can i start one of my app activity when a person trun on his phone... and startup for my app... can u? @arkascha